# Slice is not definied (when slicing strings in Array in a loop)

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I stumbled upon something that I cannot understand. Slicing strings in Array in a loop gives a `"Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined"` error. When I slice any string of Array on its own (without the loop) it works fine. Please help me debug the code.

```js
var Arr = ['2018-08-03 11:00:00', '2017-07-03 03:30:00'];
console.log('length of Arr: ', Arr.length);
console.log('string testing: ', Arr[0]);

var testing = Arr[0].slice(0,-3);
console.log('slice testing :', testing);

var chunks = [];

for (var i = 0; i<=Arr.length; i++) {

  chunks.push(Arr[i].slice(0,-3));

};

console.log('chunks: ', chunks);
```

Comment: Try `for (var i = 0; i<Arr.length; i++)` <-- Remove the `=`.

Comment: you loop over the length.

Comment: @Eddie thanks! But it should loop once? since 0 is <= 1 ?

Comment: With `<` it will loop once, if there's a single memeber in the array, twice if there are two members etc ... See how [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `i<=Arr.length` in the `for` loop condition which is incorrect. This is incorrect because the length of `Arr` is `2` so when the value if `i` is `2` it is true in `for` loop when we have `i<=Arr.length`. So, when the code `Arr[i]` executes with `Arr[2]` it cannot find any element in third index (since Arr[2] means item in third index), so it gives that `undefined` error:

```js
var Arr = ['2018-08-03 11:00:00', '2017-07-03 03:30:00'];
console.log('length of Arr: ', Arr.length);
console.log('string testing: ', Arr[0]);

var testing = Arr[0].slice(0,-3);
console.log('slice testing :', testing);

var chunks = [];

for (var i = 0; i<Arr.length; i++) {

  chunks.push(Arr[i].slice(0,-3));

};

console.log('chunks: ', chunks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `=` as everyone suggested from your line - `for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)`. Otherwise, `i` gets a value equals to `arr.length`(i.e. 2) at the last iteration which index does not exist for the array! An array with 2 elements have indices 0 and 1. Similarly, an array with 3 elements will have indices 0, 1 and 2. I hope you understood the point.

Apart from that, to avoid anything like this, the safest approach to iterate over
an array is like below-

```
arr.forEach(function (item) {
   chunks.push(item.slice(0, -3));
});
```

This also makes your code more readable.

Answer (score -1):

Your loop should begin 0 to Arr.length

```js
var Arr = ['2018-08-03 11:00:00', '2017-07-03 03:30:00'];
console.log('length of Arr: ', Arr.length);
console.log('string testing: ', Arr[0]);

var testing = Arr[0].slice(0,-3);
console.log('slice testing :', testing);

var chunks = [];

for (var i = 0; i<Arr.length; i++) {

  chunks.push(Arr[i].slice(0,-3));

};

console.log('chunks: ', chunks);
```